# C# Reflection- Find if a class has defined destructor

Tags: c#, reflection, destructor

I am trying to find if a class has destructors using reflection. I do see methods to get  constructors in System.Reflection. Is there a way to find if a class has defined custom destructors in C#?

Comment: Are you looking for classes that implement IDisposable?

Comment: There are only Finalizers in C#. I do not see the point of knowing if a Finalizer exists on a type (even though they do internally anyway).. because you shouldn't care if it does.. only the Garbage Collector should care.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead [Destructors in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) call Finalize()

Comment: @jltrem Its such a bad term.. which is why I like to call out the difference. A Finalize method does not correspond 1 to 1 with what most people consider a Destructor to do. You'll note that in the documentation it does not state "implicitly calls Finalize on the current object". It in fact is converted into a Finalize method, and that finalize method implicitly calls the base `object` finalizer. Theres a difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The destructor method seems to be  called `Finalize()`.  All objects have this, so you want to check if it's explicitly defined on that object by trying to get it with the `DeclaredOnly` binding flag.  It's also private and non-static so you need the other two flags as well.

```
myObj.GetMethod("Finalize",
                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

This will return null if the object doesn't have a defined destructor.

Comment: A C# destructor implicitly calls Finalize().  But it could do other things as well.

Comment: @jltrem Google was timing out for me, so I said this based on a stack trace from destructor.  The article you posted seems to say that the destructor syntax is syntactic sugar for a `Finalize` method which implicitly calls the base class `Finalize` method too.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Exactly what I'm saying in the comments on the question. It doesn't "implicitly call Finalize".. it is converted into a Finalizer, and it implicitly calls the finalizer of the base class.

Comment: every time I read up on this I seem to toggle my understanding!  Thanks for keeping me digging.

Comment: OK, just searched ECMA-334 and they have abandoned the term _destructor_:  "17.12 Finalizers Note: In the previous version of this standard, what is now referred to as a 'finalizer' was called a
'destructor'. Experience has shown that the term 'destructor' caused confusion and often resulted to incorrect expectations, especially to programmers knowing C++. In C++, a destructor is called in a
determinate manner, whereas, in C#, a finalizer is not. To get determinate behavior from C#, one should use
Dispose.".  The index has destructor listed as "see finalizer".

Comment: One minor nitpick: Just checking for a method called `Finalize` should usually work just fine, but could give false positive results: It's possible to declare a `void Finalize()` method that is not an override of `object.Finalize`. AFAIK, you'd additionally have to check whether `finalizeMethod.GetBaseDefinition() == typeof(object).GetMethod("Finalize", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)` to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Check reflection for the existence of Finalize defined on the instance in question.

The ~ClassName syntax is translated to a Finalize() method on the object.

All .NET objects have a Finalize method defined at the System.Object level.